# GeForce 6200 (NV44) Xubuntu 18.04 (Kernel 5.3.x) driver

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, nvidia-geforce

I have installed `Xubuntu 18.04.03`. It comes with `Kernel 5.0.0-23` (previous I have written 5.2 but I was wrong). After a system update kernel has been updated to `5.3.0-28`. I'm trying to install NVIDIA driver for my card and I follow 3 ways:

**Additional Drivers**:

The panel says me that there is a suitable NVIDIA driver for my card. I select it, click Apply Changes, nothing happend.

**Via PPA**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304
```

but also this procedure doesn't work.

**Downloading Original Driver and patching it**:

```
sudo apt install gcc make build-essential gcc-multilib dkms mesa-utils
```

**Download driver** from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/123708/en-us

**Download patch** from https://adufray.com/nvidia-304.137-bionic-18.04.patch

**Extract archive, place patch into extracted folder and apply patch**

```
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.137.run -x
cd ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.137
patch -p1 < nvidia-304.137-bionic-18.04.patch
```

**Disable nouveau driver**

```
cat << END > /etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
blacklist amd76_edac
options nouveau modeset=0
END
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

**Stop x-server**

Ctrl-Alt-F1, login ->

```
sudo -i
service lightdm stop
init 3
```

From driver (patched) path:

```
./nvidia-installer
```

but nothing works.
Thank you

Comment: Kernel 5.2 was only a *testing* kernel for Ubuntu, 4.15 was the original supported kernel, or with HWE enabled it's now 5.3.  Have you tried using the supported Ubuntu kernels?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This version of kernel comes with updates.. I have just install Xubuntu 18.04 LTS and then run the suggested update. I have just do some to install RALINK wifi Adapter.. how can I downgrade it?

Comment: Updates found in 5.2 will of course exist in 5.3, however 5.2 won't have all the updates that exist in later 5.3 (*unless you've patched them in yourself or had someone do it for you*) so I don't see your point.  Given you've gone outside Ubuntu repositories for your kernel, I don't know what you've done (an official 18.04 build will be using 4.15 or 5.3 kernels) so I'd suggest editing your question & outlining what you've done.

Comment: Do you know if NVIDIA Driver 304.137 is installable from "Additional Driver" with an older version of Xubuntu/Ubuntu?? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know at the current moment there is no way to install such legacy driver upon linux system with 5.3+ kernel.
I had Elementary OS Freya and working bare 304.137 driver (no patch). Yesterday I switched to Elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera (based on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) with 5.3.0-46 kernel. Sadly both original version and patched one ( I had x64 version of the driver rather than 32 which you've mentioned though) failed to build.

UPDATE:
I found [this post](http://blog.schmorp.de/2019-08-03-nvidia-legacy-304-patch-for-post-50-linux-kernels.html) which describes how to patch a Debian system. It doesn't work with extracted `.run` archive tough. Not sure how to use it properly on Ubuntu.